# Miembro de datos mutable en C++

Tags: c++, poo

Buenas a todos,

a ver si me sacáis la duda. Una función constante en teoría sólo se usa con miembros de datos const que no modifican al objeto, es decir, dicha función accederá a miembro de datos const pero según estoy mirando, cuando añadimos mutable a un dato:

```
class x
{
private:
mutable int miembro_datos;
}
```

Este miembro se puede usar con funciones const y además, podrá ser modificado, lo que me lleva a una controversia.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a comprender el atributo mutable?¿Porqué con mutable sí se puede cambiar el dato de un objeto a través de una función const? ¿En teoría no debería de permitir su modificación no?

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Por qué con mutable sí se puede cambiar el dato de un objeto a través de una función `const`?

Porque así es como funciona C++; es una característica del lenguaje descrita en el estándar del lenguaje (traducción mía):

> #### 10.1.1 Especificadores de almacenamiento en clase
>
> 8. El especificador `mutable` debe aparecer sólo en la declaración de miembros no estáticos cuyo tipo no esté cualificado como constante ni como referencia [*Ejemplo:*
>
>    ```
>    class X {
>        mutable const int* p; // BIEN
>        mutable int* const q; // mal formado
>      };
>    ```
>
>    — *fin del ejemplo* ]
> 9. El especificador `mutable` sobre un miembro de una clase anula el especificador `const` aplicado sobre el objeto propietario y permite la modificación del objeto miembro mutable incluso aunque el resto del objeto sea `const`.

Así que la modificación de sub-objetos mutables no solo está permitida, si no que regulada en el estándar.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. `mutable` no se propaga a punteros a miembro:

   ```
   struct S
   {
       mutable int i{};
   };

   int main()
   {
       const S s{100}; // s es constante.
       std::cout << s.i; // Muestra 100

       s.i = 200; // s.i es mutable, podemos cambiarlo aunque s sea constante
       std::cout << s.i; // Muestra 200

       auto pm = &S::i; // Apuntamos al miembro mutable
       (s.*pm) = 300; // Error de compilacion, s es constante

       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Dado que las lambda generan un funtor cuyo operador de llamada es constante, sus datos miembro son constantes, por ello se requiere `mutable` para modificar los objetos capturados por valor en lambdas:

   ```
   int i = 0;
   auto lambda = [i](){ i++; };
   auto mlambda = [i]() mutable { i++; };

   lambda();  // ERROR: i es constante
   mlambda(); // Correcto.
   ```